# "Te elegimos a ti en concreto". Isn't it pleonasm? When is it allowed?

Tags: gramática

I'm reading a book and there's this phrase:

> Te elegimos a ti en concreto

I wonder in what situations should the objective pronoum be repeated this way. Or it's allowed to be repeated.

Comment: At least where I live, it is unusual to hear `me gusta...` people almost always say `a mí me gusta...` (at least when starting a sentence) as a form of politeness to emphasize that it is only your liking and not necessarily universal. Also see: http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?origen=RAE&lema=pronombres%20personales%20%E1tonos#52

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Te` is weak and unstressed. If you want to stress the fact that it was **you** the one we chose, you have to add the stressed pronoun.

> Te elegimos → We **chose** you.
>
> Te elegimos a ti → We chose **you**.

This applies in general:

> Te lo dije → I said it to you.
>
> Te lo dije a ti → I said it to **you** (and not to him)
>
> etc.

Comment: Thank you! So, correct me if I'm wrong, it's allowed to repeat the objective pronoum (I'm not sure if they call it this way) every time we want to emphasize it.

Comment: Yes. You can never omit the unstressed pronoun, but it isn't wrong to add the stressed one for emphasis.